# Logger instance doesn't return any log records

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging

This is a scenario where a module contains a *Logger* and it is being imported into another module. When *main.py* is called however, no LogRecords are written to the log. What can be revised in order for the log to be called?

```
#objects.py

import logging

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

formatter = logging.Formatter()

log_handler = logging.FileHandler('log_objects.log')
log_handler.setFormatter(formatter)
logger.addHandler(log_handler)

class Person:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

        logger.info(f"A new {self.__class__.__name__} is created.")
```

```
#main.py

from my_objects import objects

if __name__ == '__main__':
    objects.Person()
```

```
-dir/
    -my_objects/
        __init__.py
        log_objects.log
        objects.py

    -main.py
```

I'm expecting to see this in the log:
`"A new Person is created."`

Upon execution nothing shows in the log

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you do not specify a path name for `log_objects.log`, the file will be created under the directory where the Python interpreter is run, which in this case, is where `main.py` is located, rather than under the `my_objects` sub-directory.

If you want `log_objects.log` to be created under the `my_objects` directory, you can specify a relative path:

```
log_handler = logging.FileHandler('my_objects/log_objects.log')
```

Answer (score 0):

It works as expected. 'log_objects.log' is got created with valid line.
Are you expecting the text to be printed on the console as well? Once specific file handler is added the default handler will be overwritten.

(or) You possibly missing that how module load happens in python

```
$ python main.py

$ tree .
.
├── log_objects.log
├── main.py
└── my_objects
    ├── __init__.py
    └── objects.py


$ cat log_objects.log
A new Person is created.
```